# How to print the first 10 rows with columns label in SAS

Tags: sas

```
PROC PRINT DATA = pg1.eu_occ obs=10 label;
RUN;
```

I tried print first 10 observations with their label, but it doesn't work at all. Any idea how to solve this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw84W.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obs=` is a data set option, and thus must be specified in parenthesis after the data set name.  A *name=value* coded into a `Proc` statement is known as a procedure option.

Your code should be

```
proc print data=pg1.eu_occ(obs=10) label;
run;
```